# Synonimize or merge [mysql2] and [node-mysql2]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The title says it all.

[mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2) has ten times as many questions as [node-mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-mysql2)

I don't have enough rep to suggest this by the usual in-system method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say *disambiguate* them, not *merge*.

If you take a look at the [mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2) tag wiki and excerpt, you will notice that it is about a Ruby gem. The [node-mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-mysql2) seems to be about the MySQL [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) for Node.js. It is true, however, that some (91 question ATTOW) use [[mysql2] + [node.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2+node.js+-node-mysql2) combination to "build" [node-mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-mysql2) (there are also those who slap [all three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2+node.js+node-mysql2)).

Unless you want to start another holy war on "builder" ([lang] + [subject]) vs "kebab" tags ([lang]-[subject]), I think it would be beneficial to:

1. Retag questions about the Node.js package to [node-mysql12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-mysql12)
2. Rename [mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2) tag to [ruby-mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-mysql2)

Since the usage seems to be quite messy, I also suggest triaging the questions first. Notably, [this set of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2+-ruby+-ruby-2.0+-ruby-on-rails-3.1+-ruby-on-rails-2+-ruby-on-rails+-node.js+-rubyonjets+-node-mysql+-ruby-on-rails-5+-ruby-2.2+-rubygems+-ruby-on-rails-3+-ruby-1.9.2+-ruby-on-rails-4+-ruby-on-rails-3.2) (there are a couple that slipped through the filter because of the max query length restriction).

Comment: I hadn't spotted the key word 'gem', only reference to Ruby in the [tag:mysql2] tag wiki. I agree - disambiguate them.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - precisely the reason to disambiguate :) Judging from the usage mess, this is a very common source of confusion. Given the fact that barely anyone reads tag wikis, it will do more good to rename the tag to explicitly mention ruby (and extend the excerpt with "do not use for questions about Node.js MySQL package").